# Add SearchView icon to AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview, searchview

I am using an AutoCompleteTextView for searching on my own server. I use the AutoCompleteTextView as a way to show suggestions to my users as they type. That's all. Since my AutoCompleteTextView is used for search, I would like to add the SearchView to the field. How might I do that?

The following is not working

```
SearchView search = new SearchView(this);
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("search_button", "id", "android");
ImageView img = (ImageView) search.findViewById(resId);
Drawable left = img.getDrawable();
mTextSearch.setCompoundDrawables(left, null, null, null);
//mTextSearch is the AutoCompleteTextView
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to display the search icon via the hint text like that

```
 String hintText = getResources().getString(where);
 Drawable searchIcon = getResources().getDrawable(btn_search);
 SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("   ");
 ssb.append(hintText);
 int textSize = (int) (autoCompleteTextView.getTextSize() * 1.25);
 searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);
 ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchIcon), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 autoCompleteTextView.setHint(ssb);
```

I don't know if it's really what you want but it's a way ;)
The drawback is that the search icon disappears when input text !